# Suggestion of how to map business entities and data entities

Tags: c#, mapping

I would like to de-couple my business data entities from my database data entities, and in this way make my application a bit more "data source independent", and in this way to switch data source all I would need to do is to create a few new repositories for the new data source.

However, I cant quite make up my mind of how to do the mapping.
My current data source is a "database" from Parse.com, and in my first attempt to do the mapping I were using AutoMapper.

What if one if my entities has a reference to itself? or what if one of the "child entities" has a reference back to its parent (sort of as EF does it)?

```
Class ParentClass
{
    public string Name { get;set }
    public IEnumerable<ChildClass> Children { get;set; }
}

Class ChildClass
{
    public string Name { get;set }
    public ParentClass Parent{ get;set; }
}
```

I assume that if I map this up, it would end up in a loop?

Another problem I'm having is that what if for instance Children would have some really deep reference properties?

Lets for instance pretend that a `ChildClass` looks like this

```
Class ChildClass
{
    public string Name { get;set }
    public ParentClass Parent { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildClass> Children { get;set; }
}
```

I know this might be a stupid example, but in this case a `ChildClass` object could have a very deep going reference to a bunch of children and these children might have a bunch of children and so forth.

If I would map this using AutoMapper I would end up actually mapping all these children until there is no children left to map. But what if I'm not actually in need of all the "sub-children"?

Is there a way to make it "lazy load" the children on property use?

As an example:

```
myParentObject.Children.FirstOrDefault().Children.FirstOrDefault().Children.FirstOrDefault()
```

That would cause the Children property to only get loaded "on call"

Any suggestions as to how to map your data entities to business entities?

I assume that what I'm actually looking for is something that makes it possible to have custom business entities that's treated in the same way as entity framework treats its entities.

Answer (score 0):

Your repositories could return simple poco dto objects (yes, I know the "o" in poco and dto already stands for "object"). Theese do not need to have such complexities like a backlink to the parent. They are just hierarchical. Master with list of details and so on. Some have references to some lookups. Here you could get into trouble if two objects point to the same lookup object and you can't manage to make them the same. Identity Map Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern or Value Object Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object comes to help here.
Now your Mapper could be in an own assemlby that references your business entities and the dtos. So your business entities and dtos need not to know each other. In this way you have a maximum of decoupling and independance.
Your Repository should be different for every use case and should "know" which data is needed to which depth and load it accordingly. No almighty "ContactReposiory" that always loads the adresses even when not needed in all use cases. And don't use lazy loading in production. You could end up with a lot of (performance) trouble with it. (Traversing with two litte foreach could end up in 1000th of database roundtrips).
Your mapper could use automapper if suitable at least for the easy parts. The complex parts you could implement the hard way, by hand.